# Autolayout with Navigation Bar - Remove Specific Constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout, constraints

I'm building an application for iOS, which is using a navigation controller. I want to put a view in the titleView, and have it fill the whole width of the navigation bar.

I'm calling setupNavBar in viewDidLoad of the view controller that is embedded in the navigation controller. Here is how I do:

```
func setupNavBar() {
    let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar

//        navBar!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        navBar!.frame.size.height = CGFloat(100)

    let searchBar = UIView(frame: navBar!.frame)
    searchBar.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, navBar!.frame.width, navBar!.frame.height)

    searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
}
```

But the view (brown - "searchBar"), doesn't cover the full navigation bar:

[image: screenshot on the problem]

So I figured out that the problem was related to Autoresizing and Constraints, because if I call `navBar!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`, I can freely set the sizes of views frame, so there must be some constraints that change the view's bounds. But I would like to keep as much of the autolayout behaviour as possible.

Is there a way to only change the contraints on the titleView?

I'm doing everything programmatically, I don't use the storyboard or xib's!

**EDIT:**

But it doesn't seem like there is any constraints on either navigationItem or navBar:

```
for someObject in navigationItem.titleView!.constraints {
        print(someObject)
}
```

It doesn't print any constraints. neither if I use navBar.constraints!

**EDIT 2:**
I have a screenshot from "View UI Hierarchy" from the debug navigator:

[image: Close up of the problem, shown from View UI Hierarchy in xcode]
It seems that the view(brown) alligns with the Navigation Bar Back Indicator View, maybe this is a clue to what causes the problem?

**How come the view is resized?**

Answer (score 0):

Two different suggestions here:
1. You can try the

```
navigationItem.titleView.sizeToFit()
```

2. Otherwise you could set the background colour of the navbar to brown as it appears you wish the brown bar to cover the entire width of the navbar. If you want to add other views on top of that you then can.
3. You could also try to make an outlet to the title view and add an NSLayoutConstraint using

   ```
    navigationItem.titleView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint)
   ```

I am not entirely sure whether that will work, however.

Comment: 1. Didn't work.   
2. Isn't what I'm looking for.   
3. I used `NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([myNewConstraints])`, but it failed!

Comment: You can add constraints to views using view.addConstraint() and after this you should call viewDidLayoutSubviews. sizeToFit() worked for me when adding a search bar to the title view and it was not resized.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't resize. Does it have the full width of the navigation bar? When i addContraint to the searchBar view or navigationItem.titleView, I get a runtime error: "The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x13fe85720 UIView:0x13fe69fd0.width == UIView:0x13fd63070.width>
 When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself).  This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:]"